# Setting background colour of nested list elements

Tags: css

Is it possible to set the background of all the "sale" elements?  I've managed to set the "SALE" anchor tag background, like so:

```
#navigation li:last-child a {
    border-right: none;
    background: red;
}
```

I need to set the background for all the other "SALE" `li` elements.

How can I set the background for these elements with `CSS`?  I'm thinking I might need to use `JQuery`, a `CSS` would be preferable though.

```
<div id="navigation" class="cf">
<div id="hamburger_wrap">
    <a href="#" id="hamburger">Main Menu</a>
</div>
<ul style="display: -webkit-flex;">
    <li class="active">
        <a title="Home" href="/" class="active ">
          <b class="ico-home">Home</b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="Living Room" href="/Living-Room-Furniture" class="hasChildren ">Living Room</a>
        <ul class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a title="By Living Room Range" href="/Living-Room-Furniture">By Living Room Range</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Nest of Tables" href="/Nest-Of-Tables">Nest of Tables</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Coffee Tables" href="/Coffee-Tables">Coffee Tables</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="SALE" href="Top-Sale-items" class="hasChildren ">SALE</a>
        <ul class="dropdown" style="display: -webkit-flex;">
            <li>
                <a title="SALE Beds" href="/Sale-Beds">SALE Beds</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="SALE Mattresses" href="/Sale-Mattresses">SALE Mattresses</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="SALE Bed Frames" href="/Sale-Bed-Frames">SALE Bed Frames</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is

```
#navigation > ul > li:last-child a
```

demo:

```css
#navigation > ul > li:last-child a {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation" class="cf">
<div id="hamburger_wrap">
    <a href="#" id="hamburger">Main Menu</a>
</div>
<ul>
    <li class="active">
        <a title="Home" href="/" class="active ">
          <b class="ico-home">Home</b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="Living Room" href="/Living-Room-Furniture" class="hasChildren ">Living Room</a>
        <ul class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a title="By Living Room Range" href="/Living-Room-Furniture">By Living Room Range</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Nest of Tables" href="/Nest-Of-Tables">Nest of Tables</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="Coffee Tables" href="/Coffee-Tables">Coffee Tables</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="SALE" href="Top-Sale-items" class="hasChildren ">SALE</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
                <a title="SALE Beds" href="/Sale-Beds">SALE Beds</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="SALE Mattresses" href="/Sale-Mattresses">SALE Mattresses</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a title="SALE Bed Frames" href="/Sale-Bed-Frames">SALE Bed Frames</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend setting a class, `sale`, on the elements you want to style.

```
a.sale {
  background: red;
}
```

However, if you can't set a class for whatever reason, you can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
// SALE is at the beginning of the title
a[title^="SALE"] {
  background: red;
}

// SALE is found anywhere in the title
a[title*="SALE"] { 
  background: red;
}

// SALE is found anywhere in the title as a white-space-surrounded word
a[title~="SALE"] {
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to cover elements with title="SALE", title="summer SALE" and title="SALE winter".

```
a[title~="SALE"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Or assign a class to the 'SALE' elements.

Answer (score 0):

just add a `class` to the elements that you want to set the background for. If you just want a section of text to have the background, just wrap it with a `span` and set a `class` on it that has the desired background color.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [codepen](https://codepen.io/capitanflamingo/pen/jwYmQN) can help you!

```
<ul>
  <li title="sale asd">ONE</li>
  <li title="sale erw">TWO</li>
  <li title="no">THREE</li>      
</ul>


/**CSS**/
li[title~="sale"]{color:red;}
```